# PHP Chinese Characters Can't Insert To Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am using GET to pass parameters, succesful save data to mysql if the data is in english, but nothing insert if the data is in chinese.

I have detected the data encoding is utf-8, found out that using my macbook it works fine, but not working on ie. Strange,  any idea what's wrong with it?

For example

```
query("insert into Info  values ('".$email."','".$_GET['name']."')");
```

This not successful if `$name` is chinese. I have tried `echo $_GET['name']` and display normally, howerver the data can't inserted to databse is blank.

```
query("insert into Info  values ('".$email."','香港')");
```

This method successful insert data to database

Comment: Probably the data you pass over is not in an encoding that your mysql table is able to deal with and the string is truncated. Which encoding has the string and which encoding has your mysql client connection and which encoding has the column in the database?

Comment: What error messages are you receiving? Are you using a PDO connection? The SQL should be along the lines of `query("INSERT INTO info (email) VALUES ($email)");` Also, I wouldn't suggest using GET in this type of application.. I am assuming this is coming from a form? Kind of bypasses all validation.

Comment: Are you sending a "SET NAMES UTF8" query right after you've established the connection to the MySQL server? (Assuming that your data is in UTF8; if it's not, it should be.) And is your PHP string encoding configured correctly, i.e. UTF8? Does using `iconv` (see PHP manual) to convert `$_GET['name']` to UTF8 help?

Comment: How can I make sure the data is UTF8?

Comment: Use `mb-detect-encoding` and `mb-convert-encoding` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have detected the encoding is utf-8, found out that using my mac book it works fine, but not working on ie. Strange, do you have any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: I gave up for using GET to past data, and everything works perfectly now, thanks for helping and the advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you really should use POST for these operations.

Check to ensure that the column you are inserting into has the correct encoding - perhaps export the table structure for us to see if you're not sure.

As Daan said, you could try

```
query('SET NAMES UTF8');
```

Before your insert query.

Comment: I gave up for using GET to past data, and everything works perfectly now, thanks for helping and the advise.